# Find Information details from roku packaged file

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have a doubt.

If I am giving my pkg file to any other developer/user is there any chance that he can find some information from that packaged file.Is there any risk of the leakage of my code or app information.Please guys help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to extract the code from the `pkg` file, only the box has this capability.

I would recommend [this](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Packaging+Your+Application#PackagingYourApplication-RunthepackageUtility) read to have the better understanding of the packaging process.